# Trouble when switching between visual studio server to iis server

Tags: iis

I have a web application in vb.net which uses windows authentication and passes the username of the logged on user into a helper function to determine if the user is an admin.  The application then displays different menu options based on if the user is an admin or not. When I try to run this using my visual studio server the application works perfectly, but when trying to run using my IIS server, or IIS express the application does not recognize my admin rights, and the helper function paramater for the user name is empty.  Is there something I am missing on how to get IIS to recognize my admin rights?  I have disabled anonymous login for this site in iis and enabled windows authentication.

Comment: Your description is fine, but it would be help to see a small snip-it of code to show how you are getting the user's identity.  Also, what version of IIS and how do you know the user name is empty?

Comment: iis is 6.1, I put a break point on Dim username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Replace(settings("Domain"), "") and the username shows as nothing when the program is running.